# meteor email sends then does not

Tags: email, meteor, passwords

meteor send email works in development mode via mailgun

then after meteor build the packaged code fails

Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' AuthError: Invalid login - 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled

no errors with same mailgun smtp settings in development mode ?

Answer (score 0):

now it works

tests show that email.js can work with simply 'snmp://localhost:25'

however the 'account-ui-bootstrap-dropdown' does not, so it maybe an issue
with the package.

better to work directly with the api to develop login features now.